# Re-Staining Factory Finished Maple Hardwood Darker Tones

Tags: hardwood-floor, hardwood, hardwood-refinishing

I'm pretty familiar with the cosmetic remodeling trades (plumbing, electricity, drywall, and tile) and reasonably handy.

I'm closing on a 15 year old house, with 2,800 sq. ft. of orange / mahogany factory finished maple.

Our original intent was to re-stain the maple a walnut dark brown type color.

I did some research and I now see that maple supposedly does not take stain well due to not being as porous as other woods (like oak).

I've also read you can "dye" the maple instead of staining it.

Has anyone had experience dyeing maple a very dark color?  Did it come out well?

I'm not intending to DIY this project since the cost of the maple is so high (and messing it up is pretty likely as a first timer), but my initial flooring contractor did not mention anything like this and I'm worried the stain will come out mottled and blotchy on maple.

Comment: Test it on a practice piece...

Comment: @Solar Mike -- I'm not DIY'ing, and contractors aren't exactly coming out to restain one practice piece.  Question is general dyeing & restaining on maple as a whole.

Comment: Are you intending to use a large floor sander to take off all the factory finish down to bare wood?

Comment: @MichaelKaras - Yep down to bare wood.  HA.  Welcome from EE, I think you've actually given me some pointers on the 8051 at some point!

Comment: @Leroy105 - Yeah I am an active contributor on the EE site. Sorry but I do not recall your name over there.

Comment: I have used maple without any issue taking stain with the exception of birds eye maple but this is true with any knot in wood that it will absorb stain differently than the rest of the board. If your grain is uniform and all the original finish is removed I see no issues staining maple.

Comment: @EdBeal - Good to hear!!!  The grain is really uniform.